# PHP Code displays only the first registered member

Tags: php, html, css

I hope you are all doing great.

Let me first explain my system. It is about checking members attestation, that is to say, when a member enters his/her ID + Certificate number, it displays for them all their information plus a button to download the certificate.

The issue is that when different IDs and certificate numbers, it every time displays only the first registered member in the database.

Here is the code :

```
    <?php
            
            require'conn.php';
        
            
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `ord`, `sname` ,`saddress` 
          ,`Certificate_number`,`Certi`,`country`,`sphone`, `Certificate_image`, 
          `Issuance_date` 
           FROM `student` WHERE `sname`= `sname` ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            
                echo "<h2 dir='ltr' class='txt1 fs-1 text-center '>  WELCOME &nbsp  " 
          .$fetch['saddress']." <br>  </h2><h5 class='text-light text-center'>AIITA wishes you 
          a good luck</h5>";    
                echo "<hr style='border-top:1px dotted red;'/>";

                
                echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                           <div class=' col lh-lg fs-5 text-success  '>Order N° </div>
                           <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['ord']."</div>   
                      </div>";
                      
                 echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                           <div class=' col lh-lg fs-5 text-success  '>Your ID Number is  
                     </div>
                           <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['sname']."</div>   
                      </div>";

                echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success  '>Doc Number </div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> 
               ".$fetch['Certificate_number']."</div>   
                      </div>";    

                echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success '>Doc Type </div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light  '> ".$fetch['Certi']."</div>   
                      </div>";  

                 echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success '>Country</div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['country']."</div>   
                      </div>";  

                 echo "<div dir='ltr' class=' row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success '>Phone N° </div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['sphone']."</div>   
                      </div>";
                      
                 echo "<div dir='ltr' class='row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success '> File Extention </div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['Certificate_image']." 
                </div>   
                      </div>";
                echo "<div dir='ltr' class='row align-items-start '>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-success '> Issuance date</div>
                      <div class='col lh-lg fs-5 text-light '> ".$fetch['Issuance_date']." 
                       </div>   
                      </div>";



           $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `Certificate_image` FROM `student` WHERE 
           sname='$_SESSION[sname]'");
           
           echo "<a class=' d-grid gap-2   mt-4     btn btn-warning' 
           href='".'..\attestation\\'.$fetch['Certificate_image']. "'  
           target='_blank'>Download My document</a>";
           echo "<a class=' d-grid gap-2   my-2     btn btn-primary  ' href='index.php'>Back 
           to homepage</a>";
           

        ?>
```

Comment: When you debug, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  You are performing two `SELECT` queries in the code shown, which is the problematic one?  How does the data returned by that query differ from what you expect?

Comment: Hello dear. actually it displays  the following errors :


Warning: Undefined global variable $_SESSION in /home3/aiita/public_html/aiita-check.com/en/home.php on line 55

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home3/aiita/public_html/aiita-check.com/en/home.php on line 55

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home3/aiita/public_html/aiita-check.com/en/home.php on line 58

Comment: You haven't shown all of your code that may cause the issue.  Are you setting the SESSION variable anywhere?  Even if you are, you have to check that it's not null.  I think this is your problem.